# Make all text box in WPF disabled

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a situation where i need to disable all my textbox on Page .
For that i am trying to use below code

```
 private void DrpDwnSelectSemTimeTable_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
    var firstlecture = this.FirstLecture.Children.OfType<TextBox>();
    var secondlecture = this.SecondLecture.Children.OfType<TextBox>();
    var thirdlecture = this.ThirdLecture.Children.OfType<TextBox>();
    var fourthlecture = this.FourthLecture.Children.OfType<TextBox>();
    var fifthlecture = this.FifthLecture.Children.OfType<TextBox>();

                    foreach (var item in firstlecture)
                    {
                        item.IsReadOnly = true;
                    }
                    foreach (var item in secondlecture)
                    {
                        item.IsReadOnly = true;
                    }
                    foreach (var item in thirdlecture)
                    {
                        item.IsReadOnly = true;
                    }
                    foreach (var item in fourthlecture)
                    {
                        item.IsReadOnly = true;
                    }
                    foreach (var item in fifthlecture)
                    {
                        item.IsReadOnly = true;
                    }
}
```

**Any My XAML**

```
    <Canvas>
            <WrapPanel x:Name="TimeTableMainWrapPanel" Canvas.Left="109" Canvas.Top="195" Height="601" Width="745>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtFirstLctrTime"  Height="24" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="115"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtSecondLctrTime" Height="23" Canvas.Left="594" TextWrapping="Wrap" Canvas.Top="189" Width="115"/>

              <WrapPanel x:Name="TimeTableSubWrapPanel" Canvas.Left="109" Canvas.Top="195" Height="601" Width="745">
                 <WrapPanel x:Name="FirstLecture" Background="#00F0F8FF" Height="392" Width="133" Margin="0,0,10,0">
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtMondayFirstLctr" Width="133" Margin="0" Height="30" FontSize="13" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtTuesdayFirstLctr" Width="133" Margin="0,38,0,0" Height="30" FontSize="13" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                 </WrapPanel>

                <WrapPanel x:Name="SecondLecture" Canvas.Top="220" Background="#00F0F8FF" Canvas.Left="270" Height="466" Width="133" Margin="8,0,10,0">
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtMondaySecondLctr" Width="133" Margin="0,38,0,0" Height="30" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtTuesdaySecondLctr" Width="133" Margin="0,38,0,0" Height="30" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                </WrapPanel>

                <WrapPanel x:Name="ThirdLecture" Canvas.Top="219" Background="#00F0F8FF" Canvas.Left="415" Height="466" Width="133" Margin="8,0,10,0">
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtMondayThirdLctr" Width="133" Margin="0,38,0,0" Height="30" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtTuesdayThirdLctr" Width="133" Margin="0,38,0,0" Height="30" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                </WrapPanel>

                <WrapPanel x:Name="FourthLecture" Canvas.Top="221" Background="#00F0F8FF" Canvas.Left="562" Height="466" Width="133" Margin="8,0,0,0">
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtMondayFourthLctr" Width="133" Margin="0,38,0,0" Height="30" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtTuesdayFourthLctr" Width="133" Margin="0,38,0,0" Height="30" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                </WrapPanel>

                <WrapPanel x:Name="FifthLecture" Canvas.Top="220" Background="#00F0F8FF" Canvas.Left="710" Height="466" Width="135" Margin="18,0,0,0">
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtMondayFifthLctr" Width="133" Margin="0,38,0,0" Height="30" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtTuesdayFifthLctr" Width="133" Margin="0,38,0,0" Height="30" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                </WrapPanel>
            </WrapPanel>
 </Canvas>
```

Is there a better way of doing this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<WrapPanel x:Name="TimeTableMainWrapPanel" IsEnabled="False">
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your all textboxes under stack panel as below:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackPanel x:Name="TextboxContainer" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <!-- All textboxes here -->
    </StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Cancel" />
</StackPanel>
```

Now when you click a button or any event is getting triggered, inside event disable the stackpanel like below:

```
TextboxContainer.IsReadonly = true;
```

So you don't need to loop through all controls on page not even each textbox. So for me this is more optimized and fastest way to achieve your goal.

Note: Extra stackpanel would be there so see your feasibility first!

Ask me if you have any problem.